# Regex to match if word is included at least N times

Tags: regex

Trying to create a SpamAssassin custom rule that matches if the phrase "SEO" is included in an email body four or more times.

Why doesn't a simple pattern like this match true?

/(SEO.*?){4,}/m

Comment: The very first match probably already eats up all available characters.

Comment: @RadLexus : No, it doesn't, because of the lazy modifier : ".*?" should only match characters until the next SEO.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it.
You don't need the "m" modifier, because you don't use either ^ or $.
You need the "s" modifier, to allow use of . to match a newline character.

Your regex would be fine for finding a line containing 4 times SEO, but not for 2 lines each containing 2 SEO.
See "Substitution Operator Modifiers" in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_regular_expression.htm

```
/(SEO.*?){4,}/s
```